Allow users to tag pages in any site in a hub and have that show as highlighted content or news
I've got a hub with multiple associated sites, all with different owners. I'd like the owner of any site to be able to tag a news posting on their site as "Front Page News", or something like that, and have it show up in the news or highlighted content web part.
I initially added a term to the term store with different values for content topics (such as "front page news", "good news", "project update", etc.) thinking this would be a great way to filter content for different audiences in different areas of the main site. I can make this work in a single site by adding a managed metadata column to the page library and filtering news on an associated page property. Switching to all sites in the hub removes the page property option. Is there a way to add a column to all page libraries such that this will work?
All searches I can come up with lead back go search optimization across sites, and not filtering in web parts. Being relatively new to SharePoint, I expect I'm missing a key concept but haven't been able to pinpoint where. Looking at another answer, it was suggested to use a refinableString, but in that case I'm lost how to connect that refinable string to a property in the page that users can update.
